# Using Windows API functions in C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke

So, I want to use the CreateProcess API function in C#. I know that I have to import the kernel32.dll file and overwrite the function header and mark it as extern. I also  know that I have to implement the structures that the function uses. The problem that I have is the following: Where can I see the exact structure of the structure I need to implement?

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
public static extern HANDLE CreateThread(PSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES psa,
                                             DWORD cbStack,
                                             PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE pfnStartAddr,
                                             PVOID pvParam,
                                             DWORD fwdCreate,
                                             PDWORD pdwThreadID);
```

I need to implemenent the following structures in order for this to work: HANDLE, DWORD... and the rest how do I do this?

Comment: What have you done thus far?

Comment: I know how to use the function in C++, but I want to learn how to use them in C# also, I need a place where I can see The HANDLE structure so I can write the HANDKE structure in C#, I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Other people have answered, so I'm just going to slip this in here [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getfunctionpointerfordelegate.aspx]. Though my question is why are you going for this and not trying for C# multithreading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to re-implement those types. You just need to translate them to their appropriate .NET equivalent:

[Platform Invoke Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac7ay120.aspx)

You may also be interested in knowing that .NET has its own way of creating both Threads and Processes:

[Process Class (System.Diagnostics)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)

[Thread Class (System.Threading)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to Api functions. This is the best answer to my question

Comment: FWIW, you need to do more than just map the types. If that's all there was to p/invoke, this would not exist: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pinvoke

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - There's more to P/Invoke, yes. But the OP specifically asked about re-implementing the data types. In that case, finding the appropriate .NET type to use is appropriate.

Comment: Well, right off the bat, your link (which is certainly useful) does not have `PSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES`, `PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE`, `PDWORD`, `STARTUPINFO` or `PROCESS_INFORMATION`. These are two of the more complex Win32 APIs to use and just knowing that `DWORD` maps to `uint` and `HANDLE` to `UIntPtr` is really just scratching at the surface. My comments here are aimed at @juice in any case. You certainly answered the question that was asked.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/) as a source of Win32 API translations. For example, here are the two you are interested in:

- [CreateProcess](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/CreateProcess.html)
- [CreateThread](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/CreateThread.html)

Do be warned that the translations there are of variable quality. For example, there are two versions of `CreateThread` at the link above. Only one of them is accurate. It's obvious which one it is!

More generally you should have a good read of the MSDN [p/invoke tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468.aspx), and [Marshaling Data with Platform Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzhhdwae.aspx).

Comment: Kernel32 version of [`CreateProcess`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/CreateProcess.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that is really interesting!

Comment: @CodesInChaos Thanks, I was sloppy, I fixed the link

Answer (score 1):

I've found the MSDN topic [Windows Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx) to be helpful in identifying the various type aliases used in windows DLLs.

Comment: Thank you, though the above answer was much more usefull to me.